# how to make a bar multicolor in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

In this chart i want that 0 to 20 should be green 20 to 40 should be yellow and above 40 should be red , for example if we talk about divisioname D then its bar should contain all the three colors from 0 to 20 it should be green from 20 to 40 yellow and after 40 it should be of red color, I have not been able to achieve this please help

Current dataset looks like this
[image]

Comment: I tried adding calculative field in data set but that does't helped

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a ciomplete answer, it's just to point you in the right direction and I can't fit it all in a comment....

If you want a single bar showing different colours, you will have to change your query considerably. You basically need to create a horizontal stacked chart. You'll 3 series, one for each colour and the dataset will have to return values for each.

For example, your Divisionname D row would now become 3 rows

```
Category       Value Series
Divisionname D 20    'Green'
Divisionname D 40    'Yellow'
Divisionname D 39    'Red.
```

You can format each series to match the series colour and once stacked, they will add up to 79 as in your image.

Hope this help you get started.

Comment: but i cannot create such dataset

Comment: what does your datset look like at the moment? Post your dataset query and the raw data.